# The birth date I'm trying to display is not in the format that I want: Day of week, Month Day, Year

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to take user input of a birthday in form MM/DD/YY and change it so it prints day of week, month day, year. I am in an intro class, so I have no experience in this...simple solutions appreciated.

```
birthday = input("Enter Birthday (MM/DD/YY): ")
birthday = datetime.strptime(birthday, "%m/%d/%y")
if birthday > datetime.now():
    fixed_birth_year = birthday.year - 100
    birthday = datetime(birthday.month, birthday.day, fixed_birth_year)
    birthday = datetime.strftime(birthday, "%A, %B %d, %Y")
print("Birthday: ", birthday)
```

I don't know what to do with lines 5 and 6. I thought line 6 would be my answer but it prints out as year-month-day hour:minute:second

Comment: https://www.online-python.com/eunrZRYmoS is an example showing your code working

Comment: It is more useful to provide a fixed input that produces your issue.  for example, `birthday = '02/28/65'` will run the code with a mistake and produce a traceback indicating the error line and error message.  Post that in the question as well.  `birthday = '02/28/02'` won't produce an error message but gives the wrong output, because the indentation of line 6 is incorrect and only runs when the year needs a correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The year must come first when fixing the datetime year. See `help(datetime)`:

```
>>> help(datetime)
Help on class datetime in module datetime:

class datetime(date)
 |  datetime(year, month, day[, hour[, minute[, second[, microsecond[,tzinfo]]]]])
    ...
```

So use the following:

```
birthday = datetime(fixed_birth_year, birthday.month, birthday.day)
```

You can also use the `datetime.replace` method:

```
birthday = birthday.replace(year=fixed_birth_year)
```

The indentation is also wrong on the 6th line, so formatting only works when the year needs a correction.  `02/28/02` will print incorrectly.  The following code fixes both problems and gives examples:

```py
from datetime import datetime

def display(birthday):
    birthday = datetime.strptime(birthday, "%m/%d/%y")
    if birthday > datetime.now():
        fixed_birth_year = birthday.year - 100
        birthday = birthday.replace(year=fixed_birth_year)
    birthday = datetime.strftime(birthday, "%A, %B %d, %Y")
    print("Birthday: ", birthday)

display('02/28/02')
display('02/28/65')
```

Output:

```
Birthday:  Thursday, February 28, 2002
Birthday:  Sunday, February 28, 1965
```